# Activity Transition Effects

Tags: android, animation, transition

I tested my app with a Motorola Milestone and a HTC Wildfire. I have a sliding transition animation, when I change to an other activity with the Milestone. I think this is default, because I didn't add any animation to the Theme. But on the Wildfire I don't have any transition effect. Is it possible to get the default sliding transition animation working with the wildfire? I implemented the original `task_open_enter.xml` and `task_open_close.xml` in the app and changed my style according to [`Animation.Activity`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml;h=d7b654e49809cb97a35682754b1394af5c8bc88b;hb=HEAD), but this also doesn't work. Calling `overridependingtransition` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that your Wildfire phone has Animation enabled. Go to Settings->Display->Animation and verify that "All animations" selected.

Comment: Perfect, that is the solution. Sorry for opening a Question, but I thought it might be a code issue.

Comment: That's ok, this may help other developers too. :)